# For loop iterating through table

Tags: java, for-loop

Say I created a table

```
char[][] table = new char[5][5];
```

and that I wanted to iterate it using a `for loop` for creating a "space."

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++)
       table[i][j] = ' ';
```

In the second line what does the [i] mean in `table[i].length`? why can't it be just table.length like the first line? Thank

Comment: What do think about `char[][] table = new char[5][3];`?

Comment: `table.length` will give you 5 and `table[0].length` will give you 3.

Comment: `table[i].length` returns the length of each individual one dimensional array inside the two dimensional array `table` on each iteration of the outer most `for` loop.

Comment: You can create a two dimensional array having different no of columns. In that case `table[i].length` will give you no of columns for i'th row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration :

```
char[][] table = new char[5][5];
```

is equivalent to :

```
// declare array of size 5, each element is a reference to one-dimen char[] array
char[][] table = new char[5][]; 

// initialize elements of table array, i.e. each row
table[0] = new char[5];
table[1] = new char[5];
table[2] = new char[5];
table[3] = new char[5];
table[4] = new char[5];
```

Note: you could have initialized each "row" with arrays of different size, for instance

```
table[3] = new char[255];
```

and `table[1].length` will be 5, while `table[3].length` will be 255.

These sizes of ["rows"] arrays are independent of "aggregate" array size `table.length`, therefore you have to loop thru each "row" using size of this "row" array.

Answer (score 0):

It is there because you are iterating over two dimensional array. I recommend you to check out two dimensional array.